# Class interface or enum expected error in temperature lab. Please check and see what I did wrong and explain

Tags: java, temperature

I am getting a class interface or enum error everytime i compile this, and am getting 24 errors each time. I just cannot figure out what to do. Can you please help with fixing this code? Also, when i didnt have this problem before, when i input any number, it just printed out all the answers. If possible, please recreate this code, and tell me how to fix the errors. I am using JCreator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Temperaturelab {
}   


    public Temperaturelab() {
    }


    public static void Temperaturelab(String[] args) {

       Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
       // Enter a temperature between -20 and 110 degrees fahrenheit.
       System.out.println("Enter temperature:");
       int temperature=input.nextInt();
       if(temperature>=75)
       {System.out.println("You can go swimming");
       }else{System.out.println("Try again");
       }
       if(temperature>60 || temperature<=85)
       {System.out.println("You can play tennis");}
       else{System.out.println("Try again");
       }
       if(temperature<10 || temperature<=32)
       {System.out.println("You can go skiing");
       }else{System.out.println("Try again");
       }
       if(temperature<=10)
       {System.out.println("You can play checkers");
       }
       else{System.out.println("Try again");
       }
       if(temperature<32 || temperature<=70)
       {System.out.println("You can play soccer");
       }
       else{System.out.println("Try again");
       }

    String answer;
boolean yn;

System.out.println("y/n");
while (true) {
  answer = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
  if (answer.equals("y")) {
    yn = true;
    break;
  } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
    yn = false;
    break;
  } else {
     System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Please answer y/n");
public Temperaturelab() {
  }










    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually eclipse is preferred for java development. You did silly mistakes while coding for e.g 1) There were 2 constructors with the same signature which is not allowed in java. 2) You used variables which were not declared like "in" in the while loop to accept user input for "y/n". 3) your missed in enclosing of brackets. Try writing your code on your own instead of copying it from somewhere. Below is the rectified code. Help your self.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TemperatureLab {

    public TemperatureLab() {
    }

    public static void Temperaturelab(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Enter a temperature between -20 and 110 degrees fahrenheit.
        System.out.println("Enter temperature:");
        int temperature = input.nextInt();
        if (temperature >= 75) {
            System.out.println("You can go swimming");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        if (temperature > 60 || temperature <= 85) {
            System.out.println("You can play tennis");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        if (temperature < 10 || temperature <= 32) {
            System.out.println("You can go skiing");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        if (temperature <= 10) {
            System.out.println("You can play checkers");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        if (temperature < 32 || temperature <= 70) {
            System.out.println("You can play soccer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }

        String answer;
        boolean yn;

        System.out.println("y/n");
        while (true) {
            answer = input.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
            if (answer.equals("y")) {
                yn = true;
                break;
            } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                yn = false;
                break;
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Please answer y/n");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I copied the while loop for user input y/n from our teacher, because she did not teach it at that time. Other than that, thank you for helping me! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the errors and fix the errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperaturelab {

    private Temperaturelab() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Enter a temperature between -20 and 110 degrees fahrenheit.
        System.out.println("Enter temperature:");
        int temperature = input.nextInt();
        if (temperature >= 75) {
            System.out.println("You can go swimming");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        if (temperature > 60 || temperature <= 85) {
            System.out.println("You can play tennis");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        if (temperature < 10 || temperature <= 32) {
            System.out.println("You can go skiing");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        if (temperature <= 10) {
            System.out.println("You can play checkers");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        if (temperature < 32 || temperature <= 70) {
            System.out.println("You can play soccer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }

        String answer;
        boolean yn;

        System.out.println("y/n");
        while (true) {
            answer = input.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
            if (answer.equals("y")) {
                yn = true;
                break;
            } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                yn = false;
                break;
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Please answer y/n");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there was a lot of errors that were pulled up in eclipse that Mrunal Gosar talked about but I did solve the main issue of all your answers showing up at one time. The main reason was do to the if statements. The way you were evaluating it was saying if this do this next if this do this there was nothing to compare everything one after another. 
The main point is you needed a else if statement in place of your if statements to make sure that it doesn't just list everything based on one number. 
I have  edited the code to a better example that you can clean your code up with and reapply the numbers to inside the else if statements in the mean time I have placed example numbers so you can test the code to see how it works.

The only thing I didn't change was your bottom part asking if the user entered yes or know wasn't sure what you wanted with that so I just fixed the main issue that you were having the over all issue with. Hope fully this is what you were looking for and helps out a bit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperaturelab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        // Enter a temperature 

        System.out.println("Enter temperature:");



        int temperature=input.nextInt();

        if(temperature >=95 ){
            System.out.println("You can go swimming");

        }else if(temperature >=90 ){

            System.out.println("You can go hiking");

        }else if(temperature >=85 ){

            System.out.println("You can go skiing");

        }else if(temperature >=50 ){

            System.out.println("You can play checkers");

        }else if(temperature >=40 ){

            System.out.println("You can play soccer");

        }else{

            System.out.println("Im sorry try to find something else to do");
        }



    }

}
```